# FaceBook loads HTTPS hosted iframe apps via HTTP POST (S3 & CloudFront errors)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to write a bucket policy that will allow (X-HTTP-Method-Override) because my research shows that Facebook loads HTTPS hosted iframe apps via HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET which causes S3 and CloudFront errors.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

This is what's returned from S3 if I served my Facebook app directly from S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code> 
<Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message> 
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType> 
<Method>POST</Method> 
<RequestId>B21565687724CCFE</RequestId> 
<HostId>HjDgfjr4ktVxqlIBeIlvXT3UzBNuPg8b+WbhtNHOvNg3cDNpfLH5GIlyUUpJKZzA</HostId> 
</Error>
```

This is what's returned from CloudFront if I served my Facebook app from CloudFront with S3 as the origin:

ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

I think the solution should be to write a bucket policy that makes use of X-HTTP-Method-Override... Probably I am wrong though. A solution to this problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After trying many different ways to get this to work, it turns out that it simply is not possible to make the POST to static content work on S3 as things stand.  Even if you allow POST through Cloudfront, enable CORS, change the bucket policy so that the Cloudfront origin identity can GET/PUT etc. it will still throw an error.

As an aside, S3 is not the only thing that balks at responding to such a POST request to static content.  If you configure `nginx` as an origin for a Facebook iframe you will get the same 405 error, though you can work around that problem in a [couple of ways](http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/) (essentially rewriting it to a GET under the covers).  You can also change the page (though still static) to be a dynamic extension (`.aspx` or `.php`) to work around the issue with nginx.

You can host all your other content on S3 of course, and just move the page that you POST to onto a different origin.  With a decent cache time you should see minimal traffic, but it will mean keeping your content in two places.  What I ended up doing was:

- Creating EC2 instances in an autoscaling group (just in case) to serve the content
- They used a cron job to sync the content from S3 every 5 minutes
- No change in workflow was required (still just upload content to S3)

It's not ideal, nor is it particularly efficient, but hopefully it will save others a lot of fruitless testing trying to get this to work on S3 alone.

Comment: Have this issue with a CF dist., thank you. In 2nd sentence 3rd line I think you mean 'though you can ... ' rather than ' you an'. Tried to edit but need six modifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your Cloudfront distribution to allow POST methods.

If you go into your dashboard and edit the Behavior for the distribution
 - Then select **Allowed HTTP Methods** - GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS

This allows the POST from Facebook to go through to your origin.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with S3 and CloudFront for last couple of days. and I confirm that with any bucket policy we cannot redirect POST calls from Facebook to S3 static (JS enriched) contents.

The only solution seems to be the one Adam Comerford mentioned in this thread:

Having a light application which receives Facebook calls then fetching the content from S3 or CloudFront.

If anyone has any other solution or idea it will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can't change POST to GET - that's the way Facebook loads app page because it also sends data about the current user as POST body (see [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) for more details). I would suggest you look into fixing your app to make sure it properly responds to POST request.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, the applicaition is hosted on S3, which states that POST is supported, but is throwing an error